# Errors with conditional etree lxml

Tags: python, lxml, xml.etree

I'm trying to delete everything between  if between  is number 66:

I get the following error: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable...if element.tag == 'answer' and '-66' in element.text:

What is wrong with that? Any help?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- 

from lxml import etree

planhtmlclear_utf=u"""
<questionaire>
<question>
<questiontext>What's up?</questiontext>
<answer></answer>
</question>
<question>
<questiontext>Cool?</questiontext>
<answer>-66</answer>
</question>
</questionaire>

"""

html = etree.fromstring(planhtmlclear_utf)
questions = html.xpath('/questionaire/question')
for question in questions:
    for element in question.getchildren():
        if element.tag == 'answer' and '-66' in element.text:
            html.xpath('/questionaire')[0].remove(question)
print etree.tostring(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element.text seems to be None on some iterations.  The error is saying that it cant look through None for "-66", so check that element.text is not None first like this:

```
html = etree.fromstring(planhtmlclear_utf)
questions = html.xpath('/questionaire/question')
for question in questions:
    for element in question.getchildren():   
        if element.tag == 'answer' and element.text and '-66' in element.text:
            html.xpath('/questionaire')[0].remove(question)
print etree.tostring(html)
```

The line its failing at in the xml is `<answer></answer>` where there is no text in between the tag.

---

**Edit** (*for the second part of your issue about combining tags)*:

You can use `BeautifulSoup` like this:

```
from lxml import etree
import BeautifulSoup

planhtmlclear_utf=u"""
<questionaire>
<question>
<questiontext>What's up?</questiontext>
<answer></answer>
</question>
<question>
<questiontext>Cool?</questiontext>
<answer>-66</answer>
</question>
</questionaire>"""

html = etree.fromstring(planhtmlclear_utf)
questions = html.xpath('/questionaire/question')
for question in questions:
    for element in question.getchildren():   
        if element.tag == 'answer' and element.text and '-66' in element.text:
            html.xpath('/questionaire')[0].remove(question)

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(etree.tostring(html))
print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<questionaire>
 <question>
  <questiontext>
   What's up?
  </questiontext>
  <answer>
  </answer>
 </question>
</questionaire>
```

Here is a link where you can download the [BeautifulSoup module](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.x/).

---

Or, to do this a more compact way:

```
from lxml import etree
import BeautifulSoup    

# abbreviating to reduce answer length...
planhtmlclear_utf=u"<questionaire>.........</questionaire>"

html = etree.fromstring(planhtmlclear_utf)
[question.getparent().remove(question) for question in html.xpath('/questionaire/question[answer/text()="-66"]')]
print BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(etree.tostring(html)).prettify()
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me one further step:-P I'm getting now the output:<questionaire>
<question>
<questiontext>What's up?</questiontext>
<answer/>
</question>
</questionaire>     .......so answer is not fully shown...why is that?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to checking if `element.text` is `None`, is to refine your XPath:

```
questions = html.xpath('/questionaire/question[answer/text()="-66"]')
for question in questions:
    question.getparent().remove(question)
```

The brackets `[...]` mean "such that". So

```
question                          # find all question elements
[                                 # such that 
  answer                          # it has an answer subelement
    /text()                       # whose text 
  =                               # equals
  "-66"                           # "-66"
]
```

Comment: this solves the problem, that he is not touching the other answer elements...with the above example i'm getting the answer elemts cut...but i dont know why...anyway with this solution it works!

Comment: no sorry...he is cutting the empty answer tags...why does that always happen?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean `<answer></answer>` is being shortened to `<answer/>`? That's okay; they are equivalent.

Comment: Yes..thats what i meant...but what can I do to prevent that? Because i need the Tags for proper Formatting..? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `import lxml.html as lh`. Then `lh.tostring(html)`.

Comment: In fact, if you are dealing with HTML, then you should be using `lxml.html` instead of `lxml.etree`.